# Centos 6.5 super user root lost

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system, centos

When I try to log in as root, the system show:
"Login incorrect", I'm sure my password is correct, but just in case I decide to use single mode to reset it. But no help.

Then I change the following 2 files

**/etc/passwd**

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

***to***

`root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

also **/etc/shadow**

`root:$2a$05$sin5i458ghsdfg8076t5ymp4y;jgslkdbvffd bshmRK:12856:0:10000::::`

***to***

`root::::`

But no help. When I trying to: chage -l root

system return: "**chage: user 'root' does not exist in /etc/passwd**"

I have already check the permission of passwd and shadow
they are:

passwd:      -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1721 Oct 2 10:47

shadow:      ---------- 1 root root 2026 Oct 2 10:47

Please help find the account root back

PS: when I restart CentOS, there are some error I think I should post here:

```
Starting udev: /bin/chown: invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:disk'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:lp'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:lp'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:lp'
/bin/chown : invalid user: 'root:lp'
```

So, this issue has been solved by Cyrus's comment:

Make a copy of passwd and shadow, remove in passwd and shadow both lines of user root (UID=0 and UID=222) and create a new user root: useradd -c root -d /root -u 0 -g root -G bin,daemon,sys,adm,disk,wheel -o -M -s /bin/bash root and try to set a password.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the output of `getent passwd root`?

Comment: No output using `getent passwd root`

Comment: Is or was your system connected to a LDAP server or something similar?

Comment: No, it's a test server and isolated to any other server.

Comment: What's the output of `getent group root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel`? Do you have a backup of this server? What's the output of `getenforce`?

Comment: `root:x:0:``bin:x:1:bin,daemon``daemon:x:2:bin,daemon``sys:x:3:bin,adm``adm:x:4:adm,daemon``disk:x:6:``wheel:x:10:administrator`. No backup of the server. getenforce command not found

Comment: If you're brave you can try to create a new root user with `useradd`.

Comment: I have done that before but in the passwd there are 2 root user looks like this one is root:x:0:0:root:/root:bin/bash, one is root:x:2222:2222::/home/root:/bin/bash, and still can not login as root, when start

Comment: Based on the `/etc/shadow` output, your system seems to think it's 2005.  `12856` days since 1970 is 35 years (2005).  Should be something like `16155` (44 years).  And `:10000::::` means your password must be changed after 10000 days.  Try changing the end to `:99999::::`.

Comment: `root:$2a$05$sin5i458ghsdfg8076t5ymp4y;jgslkdbvffd bshmRK:12856:0:10000::::` is totally faked the real string now is  `root::::`

Comment: Make a copy of passwd and shadow, remove in passwd and shadow both lines of user root (UID=0 and UID=222) and create a new user root: `useradd -c root -d /root -u 0 -g root -G bin,daemon,sys,adm,disk,wheel -o -M -s /bin/bash root` and try to set a password.

Comment: Problem solved, I love you Cyrus

Comment: :) No problem. Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of passwd and shadow, remove in passwd and shadow both lines of user root (UID=0 and UID=222) and create a new user root: useradd -c root -d /root -u 0 -g root -G bin,daemon,sys,adm,disk,wheel -o -M -s /bin/bash root and try to set a password.

Answered by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)